# Remove Extra CSS Spacing on the Bottom

Tags: html, css

Here is the problem. I have a problem with an iframe that has an extra space on the bottom and pushing the text down. Here is the current code that I have.

```
    iframe#resourceobject {
      max-height: 515px !important;
      height: -webkit-fill-available!important;
    }
```

The iframe contains the video, and I'm not sure the exact height of the video so it changes based on the video.

Here is the css for the text that is pushing the text close to the bottom.

```
    div#urlintro {
     vertical-align: top;
     margin-top: 10px;
     display: inline-block;   
   }
```

How can I remove the extra bottom padding so the text can stay close to the bottom of the video regardless of the video height?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as the parent window? Or if not, do you have CORS access to the third-party iframed site?

Comment: The iframe is part of the same domain.